# For Orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be any orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrix with real entries, then $d(Ax,Ay)=d(x,y)$ for any two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R^3$, where $d(u,v)$ denotes the usual Euclidean distance between vectors $u$ , $v$ in $\mathbb R^3$ .  Is this statement is true ??  I tried but I didn't get any ideas

Comment: @ancientmathematician $d(u,v)=\sqrt{(u-v)^T(u-v)}$

Comment: $d(u,v)  = \sqrt{(u - v)^T (u - v)}$ if we're working with the Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Euclidean norm $|| \cdot||$:

$||Ax||^2=(Ax,A,x)=(x,A^TAx)=(x,x)=||x||^2$, hence $||Ax||=||x||.$ Thus

$||Ax-Ay||=||A(x-y)||=||x-y||.$

Comment: Wow super Sir @Fred